# Magento Pages Showing Same Content

Tags: magento, static, content-management-system, block

I am using Magento 1.9.2. I created 3 categories active in the main navigation menu. The display mode for each category is 'static block only' and the static block each one is set to use has a unique url key, name, and content. The categories are called 'how to use', 'colors,' and 'faq.'

The problem is that when I click on one of the links on the frontend for one of those categories, the content for that category/cms block displays fine, but if I click on another link the url changes correctly but the content stays the same. For example, if I click on the how to use link first, I get the right content, but then if I click on the faq link the url changes to the faq page but the page keeps displaying the content for the how to use page.

Flushing the cache and reindexing only works for one click on one of the links. In other words, if I have the problem described above and then flush the cache/reindex the site and click on the faq link, the content changes to the faq content, but if I then click on the colors link I have the same problem.

Has anyone ever encountered this before and/or can explain why this problem is happening?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by downloading Magento 1.9.2.1 and uploading app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Block/Block.php to app/code/local/Mage/Cms/Block/Block.php.